# Convert datetime column to 24 hour format

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a column called schedule_time (datetime) format. I want to convert the time to 24 hour time.

```
2016-03-08 03:00:00 to 2016-03-08 15:00:00
```

Comment: How do you know that `03:00:00` really means `15:00:00`? Would simply adding 12 hours solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that DATETIME values are *always* stored in 24h format (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). There is no AM/PM.
When you want to *display* the values, there is however the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
function, which will format the value according to your needs, including AM/PM:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(schedule_time, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p') from t1;
```

This will give `2016-03-08 03:00:00 AM` and `2016-03-08 03:00:00 PM`. But the values in the DB are still the same, in 24h format.

If adding 12 hours would solve your issue, the you can do it like this:

```
start transaction;

update t1 set schedule_time = date_add(schedule_time, interval 12 hour); 
select * from t1; -- verify!!!

rollback;
-- or commit;
```

I put this in a transaction so you can first verify your results. If they are wrong, simply rollback the transaction (provided you use InnoDB tables). If you don't have transactions (or feel uncomfortable with them), you can undo the change with `date_sub` instead of `date_add`.

**But be aware:** This doesn't change from 12h to 24h format, it simply adds 12 hours to all your `schedule_time` values.

Answer (score 2):

Use MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

The format string will be '**%Y-%m-%d %T**'.

**Selecting the current date with 24-hour time:**

`mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS now
+---------------------+
| now                 |
+---------------------+
| 2016-03-08 20:47:04 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

**Selecting a date with 24-hour time from a table:**

`` mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS created_at FROM test.comments;
+---------------------+
| created_at          |
+---------------------+
| 2016-02-25 16:32:12 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec) ``

Comment: According to the docs: _MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format_ so the use of DATE_FORMAT won't change anything when given that very same format.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. Are you confusing string type dates with datetime type dates?

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me as I frequently do. But the column in question, schedule_time, already is DATETIME (OP wrote that).