# convert to 24 hour format in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I have a query selecting time in the format where the time column is of the DateTime datatype.

`SELECT ul.time FROM user_logins;`

It is returning the result in this format-
`11/27/2021 9:29:46 AM`
`11/23/2021 12:48:20 PM`

Now I want it to return in the 24 hour format like
`11/27/2021 9:29:46` `11/23/2021 00:48:20`

Is there any possible way to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime column to 24 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875877/convert-datetime-column-to-24-hour-format)

Comment: Datetime types are stored and returned from the database like `2021-12-01 13:14:15`; it is whatever client or client library you are using that is producing the m/y/d and am/pm, and if you need help changing that, you need to say what client/language you are using and show your code.

Comment: @James Thanks, that question's solution solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

DATETIME values always stored in 24 hour format. As your column defined as DATETIME datatype, it's in 24 hour format

Output of DATETIME datatype:

```
2021-12-07 18:21:30.907
```

AM / PM is not mentioned by DATETIME, So We can format it.

Query: `Select CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),9)`

Output: `Dec 7 2021  7:26:55:077PM`

Comment: thanks for the answer but the question is resolved!